# Login Form in Oauth2 server doesn’t return to the Client url

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

I’m writting an Oauth2 application.
The Spring application is :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

the application.properties is

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=jerpweb
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=implementa
security.oauth2.client.authorized-grant-types=password,client_credentials,authorization_code,refresh_token
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid
security.oauth2.client.auto-approve-scopes=.*
```

and the securityConfiguration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Order(-5)
public class SecurityConfigurationOauth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailServiceImpl userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoderService passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }    

}
```

The oauth server is working with protocol **password**  ( localhost:8081/oauth/token).
if I use an oauth2 client

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class ApplicationUi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationUi.class, args);
    }
}   

security.oauth2.client.client-id=jerpweb
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=implementa
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://localhost:8081/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.client.token-name=oauth_token
security.oauth2.client.authentication-scheme=query
security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme=form
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid
```

the client is redirected to the authorization server correctly but if the authentication is successfull doesn't come back to the client.
I.e. if I call page localhost:8080/ I got redirected to   http://localhost:8081/login but if the authentication is ok the browser remains on page ttp://localhost:8081/login instead of returning to page localhost:8080/.

What is the correct configuration of SecurityConfiguration with 
an oauth2 **login form**?

Answer (score 0):

The securityConfiguration is OK the problem is how the authorization server is set up.

For some reasons **authorization server must have a context-path** so the correct configuration for server application.properties is:

```
server.port=8081
server.servlet.context-path=/uaa

security.oauth2.client.client-id=jerpweb
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=implementa
security.oauth2.client.authorized-grant-types=password,client_credentials,authorization_code,refresh_token
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid
security.oauth2.client.auto-approve-scopes=.*
```

the client mapping must be changed accordingly

```
auth-server=http://localhost:8081/uaa
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=${auth-server}/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=${auth-server}/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=${auth-server}/api/userinfo
```

With these modifications in place redirect works fine.